# React-Native debugging tools/developer menu not working on iOS device

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-debugger

We have a react-native project which is working fine in the simulator and on the device. However, we are unable to open the developer menu using the shake gesture on an iOS device.

I have seen other issues but have been unable to resolve: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5122

We have the standard configuration setup in Xcode so using the debug scheme to build.
[image: Debug configuration scheme]

The DEBUG=1 setting is also added to the preprocessor macros:
[image]

However, when shaking the device I'm just looking stupid and the menu does not show. Any idea on how to resolve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: Having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

On my Android device, I find it hard to trigger the shake gesture for the React Native developer menu -- I end up shaking the device pretty hard and on several different axes (both parallel and perpendicular to the plane of the phone) before it triggers.

Maybe try shaking harder and in more directions?

Comment: Haha, this did make me laugh. I don't think its the aggression on the shake. I've thrown it across the room and it still doesn't work :D

Comment: Dang. I don't have any other ideas to offer you, but good luck!